# Why would a class be able to cast an unrelated class with only a runtime error but not a compiler error

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors, polymorphism

Here's my code:

```
public class A {
    int size = 100;
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    interface D {

    }
    class B implements D {

    }
    class C {
        int size = 999;
        public int getSize() {
            return size;
        }
    }
    public void test() {
        D d = new B();
        System.out.println(((C) d).getSize());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.test();
    }
}
```

The code compiles without any compiler error. Why wouldn't it have a compiler error. Class C does not have any relationship with the reference type class D and the actual class type B. How did it pass the compiler check for type casting?

Comment: because its correct B is also a D due to the implementation of D

Comment: A variable of type D could be an instance of some class that implements D and is also a subclass of C. So the cast can succeed. So it compiles.

Answer (score 4):

From JLS 5.5.1, Reference Type Casting:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1

> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.

In our case, S = D (interface), T = C (class).

> If S is a class type:

S is an interface, so we skip this.

> If S is an interface type:

D is an interface, so we use this branch.

> If T is an array type, then S must be the type java.io.Serializable or Cloneable (the only interfaces implemented by arrays), or a compile-time error occurs.

T is not an array type, we skip this.

> If T is a class or interface type that is not final (§8.1.1), then if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.

We do not have this. We can certainly create one to cause this to happen, but that requires a redefinition of C to fit this model.

> **Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (because even if T does not implement S, a subclass of T might).**

In other words, the compiler has no reason to throw an error, because it is distinctly possible that elsewhere there exists a possible class that can be used to qualify the cast.

For example, you could have this elsewhere:

```
class E extends C implements D { ... }
```

Finalizing C causes a compile-time error:

```
final class C { ... }
```

Basically, there exists a possibility that there is an implementation of C that can exist that works at runtime which cannot be verified at compile time.

Comment: Basically what I was saying, but it's good to see the specs to back it up.

Comment: @xtratic I agree. From a human programmer POV, it makes sense, but for the compiler, being able to see the individual decision points gives a concrete understanding of each step going through and why things do as they do, rather than just as we understand.

Comment: Yep, that's why I was saying the specs were good to see, it's nice to have both perspectives.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my human explanation, see @Compass answer for  the details of the specification..

The reason is because you are casting from an interface where *the actual class of the instance it holds could match the class you are casting to*. `d` could hold and instance of type `C`.

Only variable type matters for compile-time while actual type of the instance matters for run-time.

See this code for an example:

```
class B { ... }
class C { ... }
interface D { ... }

// only variable type matters for compile-time
// the compiler (usually?) doesn't care what's in them
D d = ...;
B b = ...;

// compile error
// `b` can't contain an instance inheriting from `C`.
C c2 = (C) b;

// no compile error
// `d` might contain an instance inheriting from `C`.
C c1 = (C) d;


// it's because of the possibility like below
// that the compiler doesn't complain.
class E extends C implements D { ... }

D d = new E();
C c = (C) d;
```